# Sending one-byte integer using Pebblekit JavaScript?

Tags: pebble-watch

The PebbleKit Android and PebbleKit iOS libraries let you use integers of different widths when constructing app messages to send. For PebbleKit JavaScript, it seems all integers are automatically sent as 4-byte integers. Is there a way to send a single-byte integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@robert-levy is right about integers.

If you really need to, you can send one byte like this:

```
Pebble.sendAppMessage(42, [ 255 ]);
```

On the receiving side, it will appear as a byte array.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript as a language only supports a generic 'number' data type with no alternative widths.  It's a language limitation, not something Pebble could do anything about.